# VB two buttons with multiple clicks, sync issue

Tags: vb.net

I have two buttons that refer to the same forms, one allows for information to be pasted  in directly where as other is for putting information manually. When forms are completed they put the results into a text box.

What is happening is that if the input method is mixed, i,e some pasted or some manually inputted the buttons become out of sync, like button 1 may be at case 3 and button 2 will be case 5 so they may put results into wrong box or even replace an existing result.

based on the code below would there be a way to reference the state of each button, for example if button two is at case 3 then open form 5 (example).

```
Select Case _Step
            Case 0
                _Step = 1
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.TextBox6.Text) Then
                    popupform.Show()
                Else
                    Form3.Show()
                End If
                Exit Select

            Case 1
                _Step = 2
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.TextBox7.Text) Then
                    Form3.Show()
                Else
                    loadform3.Show()
                End If

                Exit Select

            Case 2
                _Step = 3
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.TextBox8.Text) Then
                    loadform3.Show()
                Else
                    loadform4.Show()
                End If
                Exit Select
```

Comment: you can add a new handler to the click everytime the button is clicked. using the removehandler button.click / addhandler button.click, adressOf ... methods. Then each handler handles a step.

Comment: cool thanks for response and help, do you have an example?

Comment: will write it as an answer if it is not usefull i will delete it again

Comment: and mark it as answer if it is useful ;)

Comment: so the code you have displayed below would that be instead of that above? in the program there will be 10 clicks on each button that assign to varying boxes, I only displayed case 1 and case 2 above but it goes up to case 10.

Comment: the code i have posted below is indeed a replacement for your solution. This is how I solve a button that has different actions with each click. Maybe someone else can give you a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public sub new()
    AddHandler Button1.Click, AdressOf firstclick
end sub

Private Sub firstclick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.TextBox6.Text) Then
                popupform.Show()
     Else
                Form3.Show()
     End If
RemoveHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf firstclick
AddHandler Button1.Click, AdressOf secondclick    
End Sub

Private Sub secondclick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.TextBox7.Text) Then
                Form3.Show()
  Else
                loadform3.Show()
  End If
End sub
```

Comment: you can also replace the button1.click in the handling methods to directcast(sender,Button).click if you want this handles to work on several buttons (sending objects have to be buttons for sure)

Comment: The two buttons are on two different forms but influence each other, how, I want it so that it handles a button from another form, how would i code that in addressof?

Comment: I would write your forms as usercontrols and then put them in one main form. This main form would contain the button of which the actions switch. then you can program the addressof function in this main form. Or is this not a possibility?